# Tree Graphs as mappings

Tags: statistics, graph-theory, machine-learning

By **tree** we mean a graph $G$ in which any two vertices $v, y$ are connected by a single **path**. Equivalently, an undirected, connected, acyclical graph.

So, there's this thing in statistics called a **Decision**, or **Regression Tree**. You feed it the algorithm a sample of data, each observation consisting of a pair $(x, y)$. Explanatory variables corresponding to a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and outcomes to $y \in Y$. If $Y = \mathbb{R}$ then it's called a regression tree, if $Y$ is closed and discrete then it's a decision tree. Once you find the better suited tree, you (ideally) have a good model for predicting these outcomes. One can extend this framework to outcomes with higher dimensionality, but let's stay with this toy model for now.

We now have to define a metric for inequality - for reasons which will soon become clear. Say you're modelling income using three variables: higher degree binary, years of experience and height. There's different ways to divide the sample of data into two parts such that the proportions of outcomes $y$ above a certain real number $m$ are the most distant. One can divide the data into people above and below the median height. There *might* be a difference in income, maybe statistically significant even. We do know however that dividing the data into people with and without college degrees likely induces a much larger difference of income across samples. That seems to be a better division of the data, in the sense that it maximizes inequality of outcomes across samples under a certain metric - or minimizes entropy within samples.

Paths from the root to leaves characterise classificafication or prediction rules such that for any $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ there is a $y \in Y$ which is the best prediction given data and hyperparameters of the tree. Each leaf/rule maps points that arrive at it to predicted values using aggregations such as mean or median of the outcome. This sounds like a function $T : \mathbb{R}^n \to Y$.

(Little détour: It seems reasonable that aggregating $k$ decision trees into a forest and averaging their predictions, if all explanatory variables are continuous then for a high enough $k$ the resulting forest $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to Y$ is continuous.)

My question is how do I represent decision trees as mappings between a vector space and some target set?

Comment: it seems like you have basically answered your own question. To define the value of the mapping on some vector in $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$, you would first check whether the condition at the root node holds. If so, then proceed to the left child node (say), and if not, then proceed to the right child node. Keep repeating this until you arrive at a leaf node; the value at that node is the value of the mapping.